# Having trouble using Visual Studio Installer - Installed program will not open

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I have Visual Studio Community 2015 and recently downloaded the add on Visual Studio Installer.
I need a simple installer for my program. I have followed quite a few tutorials on the internet on how to create this installer. 
When I run the installer, it runs fine and seems to install the program fine. However when I try to open the program nothing happens!

Sorry I don't have much information about my problem, I'm kind of hoping this may be a common problem which has a quick fix! However if not, is there another way to make an installer?

Thank you in advance
Lucy

Sorry should also mention I have tried to run it as administrator.

Comment: it probably isn't the case but just try opening it as administrator

Comment: I have tried that

Comment: and i'm guessing everything runs smoothly in your dev environment, no errors, warnings, etc? if it's an n-tier app did you set up the starting projects and all that?

Comment: Yeah it runs fine in the dev environment and it's not an n-tier app

Comment: I tried to troubleshoot the installed program and it is saying 'Incompatible Program'

Comment: ok, so, try to install it in compatibility mode with a previous version of Windows

Comment: Still doesn't seem to be working - just doesn't open at all